# Net::SMTPUnknownError (could not get 3xx (550)) error when sending email on my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, gmail

I'm using google for sending emails on my Rails 3.2 app. Most emails functions were working perfectly. Then I did some testing because delayed_job is not working. I got a warning from google that I need to log into the account via the web to unlock it (I sent about 20 emails in a span of 1 hour). Things were back to normal. Now, I am unable to send any emails whatsoever. I have this error message in my server log:

`Net::SMTPUnknownError (could not get 3xx (550))`

Has Google blacklisted me for sending 50 emails? I changed the password on the account, logged in a few times via the web, restored the settings to exactly what they were when the emails were working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got email working again by creating a new email address. Had to create a new one without using an alias for the old one to get it to work. I also created an SPF record entry, which I did not have before.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I didn't create a new email address but the SPF record did the trick. I'd never heard of an SPF record until now. For anyone else who is new to this here is google's explanation: https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786&topic=2759192&rd=1 and details for how to create an SPF record for your google app http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723